# How to inject objects of custom classes (in eclipse e4) into an Handler class (defined for a menu item in Application's XMI file)

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I'm new to Eclipse e4 and I am trying to inject an object of my custom class into a Handler class like below :

```
public class MenuHandler {

 @Inject
 Test2 user;

@Execute 
public void execute(MApplication app, EPartService partService, EModelService modelService) {

      System.out.println(user.getUserName());  // DefaultUser
      user.setUserName("anotherUser");
      System.out.println(user.getUserName()); //anotherUser

  }
}

@Creatable
public class Test2 {
  private String userName = "DefaultUser";

 public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
  }

  public void setUserName(String userName) {
      this.userName = userName;
 }


 }
```

Having this code and If I launch my RCP application, and upon clicking the menu item (defined in the 'Application.e4xmi' file) my handler class ('MenuHandler') is not getting executed. Whereas if I remove the @Inject annotation from the handler class (i.e.., upon removing  @Inject Test2 user; ) then the handler class is getting executed without any issues.

I think some problem exists if I have the annotation "@Inject" inside the Handler class.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Works fine for me testing here. There might be a message in the .log file.

Comment: After restarting my system.. it seems to be working. Don't know what could be the reason :(

Comment: @greg-449: One question with regards to DI, If suppose we didn't have any 'Application.e4xmi' file (in my product) and the 'UI/views' are similar to 3.x Eclipse (Assume that I have migrated the sources from 3.x to e4 series), then can I have DI used in my application (by having the annotations "@Inject and @Creatable") for Business logics ?

Comment: Please don't ask unrelated question in comments.

Comment: @greg-449 : Sorry Greg, Shall I post a new question ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to create and inject your custom object in the [LifeCycleManager](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html) of your e4 application.

```
public class LifeCycleManager {

    @PostContextCreate
    public void postContextCreate(IEclipseContext context) {

       final MCustomContext customContext = PersistenceUtils.load(MCustomContext.class);
       context.set(MCustomContext.class, customContext);
    }
}
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Tib : Thanks for your answer.